# Multiple Ajax request and it's downside

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am building a Mobile Application (Phone, Jquery Mobile) for Android.

It requires a user sending a message to the server side script using an Ajax request. I implemented a system such that messages sent are not sent immediately, instead they are stored in a SQLite database (this is so because, I want the user to think the message is sent even if the network is bad) and an iteration that runs every 15 seconds in the background picks it up and send it. So therefore, if 5 messages are in the SQLite database, they will be sent every 15 seconds apart.

The above system works fine when I tested it with my Android phone connected to my WAMP via Wi-Fi.

The problem I now foresee is that when I deploy on a production Server, the Ajax response from the server won't be that fast.

Is there a way to avoid a potential problem?

Note: The response from server is via json and it is essential because it will be used to delete the message from the phone SQlite Database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I read your question:

1. A user interacts with the app and this generates actions that need to be updated on your backend. (for example, "like a post", "upvote a coment" etc.)
2. You have decided that the action does not need to complete synchronously and that the user does not need to wait around for the action to be completed/acknowledged;  The user can continue on with new actions.  At some point, the user will see that the actions have been processed but immediate updates aren't important.
3. Your polling loop in the app is responsible for eventually sending the actions to the backend to be completed.  The backend acknowledges the action has been completed by sending a response back to the app to delete the pending action.

My answer based on above:

1. Since it is the app waiting on your custom protocol to complete and not the user waiting on a synchronous action to complete, you have a lot of flexibility in the server's response times.
2. More important is that your little protocol makes sure to eventually process the action on the backend and notify the client app.  You are dealing with the concept of things becoming "eventually consistent" and thus you need to design your little protocol around that:

   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency